# Ajax call not working what is wrong in this code?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**This is my view**

```
<td>  
@if (item.Flag == false)
{ 
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="@item.CustId" class="flag" onclick="flagCustomer('flase',this.id)">
   <img src="~/Images/appimg/star.png" alt="" /></a>
}
else
{   
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="flag" id="@item.CustId" onclick="flagCustomer('true',this.id)">
    <img src="~/Images/appimg/MapMarker_Flag.png" /></a>
}
</td>
```

**This is My Ajax call**

```
 function flagCustomer(flag, id) {
        debugger;
        var flag = flag;
        var id = id;
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Importantmark", "Customer")",
            data: { _flag: flag, _id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === "1") {
                    notif({ msg: "<b>Important Customer.", type: "success" });
                } else {
                    notif({ msg: "<b>error customer while important.", type: "error" });
                }
            },
            Error: function (data) {
                notif({ msg: "<b>error customer while important.", type: "error" });
            }
        });
        debugger;
    }
```

**This is my Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public int Importantmark(string _flag, int _id)
{
    Customer _customer = new Customer();
    _customer.Flag = Convert.ToString(_flag);
    _customer.CustId = Convert.ToInt32(_id);
    var result = customerBal.ImportantMark(_customer);
    return result;
}
```

This is my code When I submit click on this image my java script function is call but when I debug code that time it's shown me id and flag property.
success debugger came to success property its went outside. what is wrong in this code kindly explain me

Comment: Little typo: change flase => false

Comment: what do you mean by _success debugger came to success property its went outside._??

Comment: means : when I am debug the code that time in ajax call success property is not execute. its goes outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass contenttype and datatype it should work

```
function flagCustomer(flag, id) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Importantmark", "Customer")',
            data: "{ '_flag': '" + flag+ "','_id': '" + id+ "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === "1") {
                    notif({ msg: "<b>Important Customer.", type: "success" });
                } else {
                    notif({ msg: "<b>error customer while important.", type: "error" });
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                notif({ msg: "<b>error customer while important.", type: "error" });
            }
        });
        debugger;
    }
```

Comment: Actually I m returning int value can it take

Comment: but you are passing data in json format right ? so you have to use content type .. did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be your quotes:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Importantmark", "Customer")',
```

Also need to add content type, and don't need to reinit `flag` and `id`, so would be:

```
function flagCustomer(flag, id) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Importantmark", "Customer")',
            data: { _flag: flag, _id: id },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === "1") {
                    notif({ msg: "<b>Important Customer.", type: "success" });
                } else {
                    notif({ msg: "<b>error customer while important.", type: "error" });
                }
            },
            Error: function (data) {
                notif({ msg: "<b>error customer while important.", type: "error" });
            }
        });
        debugger;
    }
```

Comment: @MaheshGawhane Works here, is your controller called `CustomerController`?

Comment: Yes Sir  CustomerController : Controller   this is my controller

Comment: Have you tried adding a `debugger` statement to your `success`? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

First change the following line:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="@item.CustId" class="flag" onclick="flagCustomer('flase',this.id)">
```

To:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="@item.CustId" class="flag" onclick="flagCustomer('false',this.id)"> // flase to false
```

> Check if it works:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Importantmark(string _flag, string _id) //change int to string
{
    Customer _customer = new Customer();
    _customer.Flag = Convert.ToString(_flag);
    _customer.CustId = Convert.ToInt32(_id);
    var result = customerBal.ImportantMark(_customer);
    return result.ToString();
}
```